# Does an iOS virtual machine exist for Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, virtualization

Does an iOS virtual machine for Windows exist? If it doesn't are there any reason why it couldn't?

Comment: Is the iOS simulator packaged with Xcode not good enough for your needs?

Comment: I don't have a mac

Comment: Why do you need a VM? Since computers aren't powerful enough to emulate an iOS device, if you don't have a proper developer environment, you won't be able to do a lot.

What you can do is virtualize OS X and then use the simulator packaged with OS X.

Comment: You can't have a VM for IOS on Windows or OSX as IOS runs on ARM CPUs and Windows and OSX on Intel x86

Comment: This isn't nearly an answer, but there is a solution. Google iEmu, worked with the original iPhone and iPad. The guy recently made another company (virtur.al) which was bought by Cisco.

Comment: @Mark is incorrect, of course. Common architecture makes it easier to create a VM, and probably makes them run faster, but it's not a requirement. On my Windows machine, I have VMs for TRS-80s (Zilog Z80), Apple II's, and Mac OS 8 (Motorola).

So, you could create a VM for an iOS device on Windows, but you'd have to get past Apple's protections against that sort of thing, which is extremely difficult.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch What you are talking about are emulators -VMs unseparate machine all using the instruction set of the processor.

Comment: No, @Mark, an emulator is just a specific type of virtual machine. There's no requirement for a virtual machine to share the same architecture as the host. Anything can be virtualized in a virtual machine, even the processor & architecture.

Comment: @Mark, I think you are confusing Virtual Machines and Virtualization with Emulators and Emulation. An Emulator is just a type of VM, one that uses Emulation rather than Virtualization. Virtualization is used in a VM where the host architecture is replicated to the guest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Apple does not allow iOS to run anywhere else but iOS devices (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch) and the Xcode simulator. You could simulate OS X on your Windows VM application and then use Xcode to simulate an iOS device, but this would be really taxing on your computer and really not worth the effort, but you cannot simulate iOS directly on Windows because of chipsets and Apple preventing it.

Comment: *Arrrrrrrrrrrrrrghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh this is why I hate Apple.* On a more sedate note - has anything changed over the past year?

Comment: If you hate Apple, then you shouldn't try to write iOS software.

Comment: It's a very naive decision by Apple not to provide a way for developers to test their apps against Apple products, which has already cost Apple a fair share of the market. That's why people love Android. Simple, free and with a lot of support.

Comment: What about some of us that just want to debug css for a site that our client tells us that "it does not show properly in my iphone as it does in android or desktops" ?

Comment: @Eric my answer was to buy an old device for ~65€, in terms of company cost is less than the day of work an employee would take while configuring XCode, the MacOS virtual machine and all the likely unexpected problems